# Application of Lagrange theorem

Tags: derivatives

I am to show that $\arcsin(x) > x, \;\;$with $x>0$, using the Lagrange (Mean value) theorem.

I guess I might have to find a formula such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=arcsin(x)$.

Generally I find it hard to understand how to pick my a, b, and c when trying to use $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ in these kinds of problems.

Comment: Can you use corollaries of the Mean value theorem?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d\arcsin(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, from the mean value theorem we have that exists $c \in ]0,x[$ such that:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}} = \frac{\arcsin(x)-\arcsin(0)}{x-0}=\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}$$
then we have:
$$\arcsin(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$$
But $c>0$ so $\sqrt{1-c^2}<1$, then:
$$\arcsin(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}>x$$